# How to escape a dynamic regex in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, regex, nspredicate, nsregularexpression

So, I'm getting a hex string as such from the API `2f5e28285b5e3c3e28295b5c5d5c5c2e2c3b3a5c7340225d2b285c2e5b5e3c3e28295b5c5d5c5c2e2c3b3a5c7340225d2b292a297c28222e2b2229294028285c5b5b302d395d7b312c337d5c2e5b302d395d7b312c337d5c2e5b302d395d7b312c337d5c2e5b302d395d7b312c337d5d297c28285b612d7a412d5a5c2d302d395d2b5c2e292b5b612d7a412d5a5d7b322c7d2929242f`

Once decoded to a utf string, this is the regex that's formed

```
/^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/
```

This is a valid email regex as per some online regex validators. Now the issue arises in how to escape this string. I've tried the following code

```
if let data = emailRegex.hexadecimal, let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                guard NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", NSRegularExpression.escapedPattern(for: string))
                    .evaluate(with: email) else {
                        throw ValidationError.invalidInput
                }
                
                isValid = true
            }
            else {
                throw ValidationError.missingInput
            }
```

This results in the following escaped regex:

```
\\/\\^\\(\\(\\[\\^<>\\(\\)\\[\\\\]\\\\\\\\\\.,;:\\\\s@\"]\\+\\(\\\\\\.\\[\\^<>\\(\\)\\[\\\\]\\\\\\\\\\.,;:\\\\s@\"]\\+\\)\\*\\)\\|\\(\"\\.\\+\"\\)\\)@\\(\\(\\\\\\[\\[0-9]\\{1,3\\}\\\\\\.\\[0-9]\\{1,3\\}\\\\\\.\\[0-9]\\{1,3\\}\\\\\\.\\[0-9]\\{1,3\\}]\\)\\|\\(\\(\\[a-zA-Z\\\\-0-9]\\+\\\\\\.\\)\\+\\[a-zA-Z]\\{2,\\}\\)\\)\\$\\/
```

The following escaped regex results in wrong results for proper emails, it gives validation errors even for the right ones. Any help will be appreciated!

Edit 1:
Updated code to

```
let string = String(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!.dropFirst().dropLast())
```

But compiler crashes on the following -
[image]

Comment: You do not need to escape it, it is a regex, with already escaped things. To make it work in Swift you need to remove the first and last `/`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I think you should write your comment up as an answer, since it is the answer.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Please check the update

Comment: Yes, the regex you are using is JavaScript ECMAScript compliant, and in Swift, ICU regex library is used. You need to escape `[` and `]` inside character classes. Now, the question is whether you want to convert any ECMAScript pattern to ICU, or just use this email regex validation regex? Without getting it via some API?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I think I will have to convert the ECMAScript pattern to ICU as the hex string I receive is dynamic

Comment: So the question is too broad to answer. Converting one regex flavor to another is not trivial and requires a lot of effort.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Can you point me to how I would take care of escaping the open and close square brackets correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```swift
((?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*\[(?:\\.|[^\]\[])*)\[
```

Replacement: `$1\\[`. See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/GTuICY/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```swift
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?<!                     look behind to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \\                       '\'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \\                       '\'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \\                       '\'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )*                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \[                       '['
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \\                       '\'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      .                        any character except \n
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^\]\[]                  any character except: '\]', '\['
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )*                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \[                       '['
```